# computed style in setState of react doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have nested form objects but I try to setState using one handler, somehow doesn't work

```
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      form: {
        name: '',
        location: ''
      }
    }
  }

  handleFormInput = (event) => {

    this.setState({
      [this.state.form[event.target.name]]: event.target.value
    })

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.state.form)
    },50)

  }
```

`event.target.name` can be name and location.

Comment: could you please clarify your code, because next to the `constructor()`, `handleFormInput = ...` is invalid syntax, and if it is `handleFormInput: event => ...` I'd say check `this` arrow functions have no own `this`-object, they're enclosing the surrounding one. Or where exactly is `handleFormInput = event => ...` defined? The context is important here.

Comment: @Thomas why not? it's react es6. handleFormInput is onChange's listener in my jsx.

Comment: that's a part of the context I meant. So `handleFormInput=...` is inside the `render()`-function? Telling by your snippet it looked like `handleFormInput` is a method defined on your class, right next to the `constructor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly access and modify a dynamic state within the `setState` function, you would rather get a copy of the state object and modify it. Also as you may already know that `setState` is `async` and hence you have a `setTimeout` function which is not necessary since `setState` provides you a `callback` function which is executed when state has changed.

```
handleFormInput = (event) => {
    var form = {...this.state.form}
    form[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      form
    }, () => {this.state.form})

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code is not working properly:

> this.setState({
>         [this.state.form[event.target.name]]: event.target.value
>       })

alternative is :

```
handleFormInput = (event) => {
    //New code
    let obj = {}
    obj[this.state.form[event.target.name]] = event.target.value

    this.setState(obj,() => { console.log(this.state.form) })
  }
```

to view updated `state`, use callback function param of `this.setState`

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous, your state will properly update somehow after the call. Then render will be called again. Try checking your new state in render or in componentWillUpdate : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate

You should never look for a change in your state right after changing your state